# In D3, how do you conditionally nest SVG elements (in the context of 'enter')?

Tags: d3.js, force-layout

Specifically, given this example: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045

How would I nest circles inside of the others? And have those be able to link to other (parent) circles?

Comment: Would whoever downvoted care to explain?

Answer (score -1):

The key for me was to use what was returned from 'enter' for appending the children and parent SVG objects separately. e.g.:

```
var enter = svg...enter()
var node = enter.append("rect")...
var children = enter.append("rect")...
```

(see the link in the question for the entire code context)

To conditionally add children, you can use a filter as follows:

```
var children = enter.filter(...).append("rect")...
```